# How to calculate the weights in a neural network after training?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have a neural network with 1 hidden layer with 20 neurons. My training set has 8 features.

Thus, I was expecting a Input Weight matrix of 20x8, whereas on net.IW, I get a matrix of 20x10. I am a little confused regarding why this happens.

I have set no delays. I also can't figure out how I need to get the weights from the hidden layer to the output layer with 1 neuron (expecting 20x1 vector).

EDIT:

1) It does not always give 'N' features + 2 weights extra. In a different problem, I am training a different neural net which has 10 input features and 25 neurons on the only hidden layer. So, while I should expect a input weight matrix ( weights from input layer to the hidden layer ) to be a matrix of 25x10, I get a matrix of 25x16. Refer to the bottom of the [page](http://in.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/neural-network-object-properties.html) to see this

> "The (input) weight matrix has as many rows as the size of the layer it goes
>   to (net.layers{i}.size). It has as many columns as the product of the
>   input size with the number of delays associated with the weight:
>
> net.inputs{j}.size * length(net.inputWeights{i,j}.delays)"

My length(net.inputWeights{i,j}.delays) is 1, so I don't know why I get a value more than the number of my input features.

2) I have 8 neurons on the input layer ( I have 8 input features ).

3) Code to train the network.

```
net = newfit(trainX', trainY', 20 );
net.performFcn = 'mae';
net = trainlm(net, trainX', trainY');
```

[image]

Comment: I could explain 20x9 as you would get a column for *bias* . . . but not sure where the other +1 comes from.

Comment: Bias weights are different here. net.b gives exclusively bias weights. I don't think net.IW includes bias

Comment: does it always give N features + 2 weights?

Comment: What is net.IW ? Another question, how many neurons do you have on input layer, not in hidden layer?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code to train your NN? `net.IW` is part of the NN structure. Can you also post the result of `view(net)`?

Comment: I think I found the problem. While `net.inputs{1,1}.size` is 8 (as expected), the `net.inputs{1,1}.processedSize` is 10. This is why I get 10 neurons on the input layer. Now, my question is why `processedSize` more than actual `size` and how to prevent it from modifying the input layer size.

Comment: You asked this question in 2 separate question posts. This is a duplicate. I answered you in the other one.